# Nodejs Async callback issue

Tags: node.js

I would like to make a chatbot that has query function. and I'm trying to implement callback function for my project.

I wrote two functions below:
encodeData(): spliting line break "\n" for making query where conditions.
queryData(): get conditions from encodeData(), before it make query to get result.

However, I got a issue. How come queryData() ran 4 times when it is started.
and queryData() didn't return anything. Could someone help me to solved the issue? Thank you~

```
var async = require('async');
var sql=require('mssql');

var text = "";

async.parallel([
    function(queryData){
        text = encodeData("QQQQ\nEEEE\nCCCC\nDDDD\n", queryData);
    }], function(){
        //after that send message to someone.
        console.log("result: "+text);
});


function encodeData(text,callback){

    text = text.replace(/ +/g,""); 
    var result = text.split("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
        if(result[i].trim().length > 0) { 
            text += queryData(result[i]);
        } 
    }

    return callback(text);
}

function queryData(message){

    sql.close();
    var message = "";

    sql.connect(config,function (err) {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        var request=new sql.Request();

        request.query("select * from order where 1=1 and no = '123456'" ,function(err,recordset){
            if(err) { 
                console.log(err);
                message = "failure";
            } else {
                console.log(recordset);
                message = "success";
            }
        });
    });

    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yous should send `null` parameter in first `callback` arguments for `encodeData` function

```
async.parallel([
   function(queryData){
       text = encodeData("QQQQ\nEEEE\nCCCC\nDDDD\n", queryData);
}], function(error, result) {
    // Catch error 
    if (error)
         return console.error(error);

    //after that send message to someone.
    console.log("result: "+text);
});


function encodeData(text,callback){

   text = text.replace(/ +/g,""); 
   var result = text.split("\n");

   for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
     if(result[i].trim().length > 0) { 
        text += queryData(result[i]);
      } 
   }

   /*
    * If you have cache error or no have error you should send null
    */
   return callback(null, text);
}
```

Comment: I'll try your opinion. Thank you